# How to use Jinja2 with Google App Engine Python?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, jinja2, app.yaml

I am trying to use jinja2 with GAE python. Whenever I edit the app.yaml to add the

```
-name: jinja2
 version:latest
```

and try to run the app an error comes up. However when I take it out the error disappears.
here is the error

```
     File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\api\yaml_listener.py", line 226, in Parse
    self._HandleEvents(self._GenerateEventParameters(stream, loader_class))
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\api\yaml_listener.py", line 172, in _HandleEvents
    for event in events:
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\api\yaml_listener.py", line 212, in _GenerateEventParameters
    raise yaml_errors.EventListenerYAMLError(e)
google.appengine.api.yaml_errors.EventListenerYAMLError: mapping values are not allowed here
  in "C:\Users\Acer Customer\Desktop\udacity\jonponblog\app.yaml", line 19, column 10
2014-01-15 15:53:01 (Process exited with code 1)
```

Here is the app.yaml

```
    application: jonponblog
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /favicon\.ico
  static_files: favicon.ico
  upload: favicon\.ico

- url: .*
  script: main.app

libraries:
- name: webapp2
  version: "2.5.2"
- name:jinja2
  version: latest
```

Comment: You seem to be missing a space after ':' in the line '- name:jinja2'

Comment: wow, that was the error. I did not know it was that stupid. Thanks alot